# Enabling REST (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) support in iis 6

Tags: windows, iis, iis-6

I want to enable [REST](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRepresentational_State_Transfer&ei=hntwSsaAN8a5jAfUubiVBQ&usg=AFQjCNFOI2woNZ9ksjkvVmSH6EOXv_0alw&sig2=BVL2zNjFdvaREAoXF0i7Cw) support in iis 6. My Googling has shown me that i can achieve PUT requests by [enabling WebDav] , however enabling the Delete method still eludes me. I've seen suggestions about editing configuration files, however i come from an apache background, and know little about iis configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered the answer by accident, trying to enable parent paths.

Open the IIS Management console,

Right click on your website in the sidebar and go to properties.

Go to the "Home Directory" Tab

In the "applications settings", click on the "configuration" button

In the "Applications configuration" Window, there should be a Mappings Tab

Simply choose which file extensions you want to have mapped (in my case i wanted ASP to map GET, PUT, POST & DELETE), comma delimited. And thats it, not even a restart required.

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to do this to an ASP.NET MVC2 application, just put the aspnet_isapi.dll in the wildcard application maps, in the same tab Jonathan said.