# IIS 6.0 preventing "PUT" & "DELETE" method types on WCF 4.0 web service calls (403 Forbidden)

Tags: iis-6, wcf

I am a developer trying to assist my server admin in figuring out how to get this issue corrected.

But I have an app that is using WCF 4.0 configure-less setup to make RESTful webservices calls.  Everything works fine locally but when pushed to my server all PUT and DELETE requests return a 403 forbidden error.

After searching around I've been unable to find anything that seems to work, and I'm not sure if there is some logs that would help figure this out, I'm not a server guy and apparently neither is my "server guy". So any tips on where to point him or what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the allowable verbs in IIS Manager, in Home Directory/Configuration, for any given extension.  See these links for a step-by-step:

- http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx
- [Enabling REST (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) support in iis 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/47921/enabling-rest-get-post-put-delete-support-in-iis-6)